# Why are these installed packages not found in Cygwin?

Tags: python, windows, package, cygwin

I've installed Cygwin and Python in Windows, but now having added both pip and virtualenv packages, when I try to use them in the Cygwin command line I get `-bash: pip: command not found` and the same message for virtualenv. When I run `python -m ensurepip` it says the requirement is already satisfied. But when I go back to use it again, it is still missing.

Could it have something to do with where I've stored the local package directory? It's not in my main Cygwin directory.

I am new to Cygwin, so I could be missing something obvious. Thoughts?

**UPDATE:** I found pip. It's called `pip2`, so when I called `pip`, nothing happened. So this leads me to wonder if virtualenv has an alternate name as well. I did a `pip2 freeze` and virtualenv is indeed installed but I still can't seem to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I could not call `pip` or `virtualenv` because they were from packages for Python 2.7 and had been renamed to `pip2` and `virtualenv-2.7` and have to be called that way in the command line. I'm reviving an old project with old requirements, so I'm using this older version of Python.